# How to calculate mean of a column by it's number rather than name in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, mean

In my dataframe I have a column which is the month/year of the latest available data (e.g. it currently says Dec-23 as that's the latest but next month it will say Jan-24). I want to calculate the mean of this column, but I don't want to have to go in and change the column name each time. The latest month is always column 26.

OrgCode |...| Oct-23 | Nov-23 | Dec-23

OrgA    |...|  0.78  |  0.56  | 0.76

OrgB    |...|  0.36  |  0.46  | 0.74

OrgC    |...|  0.48  |  0.66  | 0.96

I have tried the following:

```
z_name = names(df[,26])
z = df$z_name
```

But get this error:

```
Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `z_name`
```

I also tried this approach:

```
mean.df.latest = df %>% mean(.[[26]])
```

But get this error:

```
Warning: argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Comment: Please provide toy data or a snippet of your real data, e.g., assuming the relevant part is encluded, the output of `dput(head(mydata))` as text, where `mydata` is your data (~`df`).

Comment: `mean(df[,26])` should do it.

However, I dont understand if "Dec-23" is the column name or a cell content.  I'm not sure if `z_name` return what you expected .Please share a reproducible example if it doesn't work, maybe with `dput()`. https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example .
`z_name` should return a string corresponding to the name of colum 26th.  You might

Comment: I've added example data - so column 1 (orgcode), column 24, 25 and 26 are featured in this table, and 3 sample rows

Comment: I assume you are looking for `colMeans()`: `X = structure(list(OrgCode = c("OrgA ", "OrgB ", "OrgC "), Oct.23 = c(0.78, 0.36, 0.48), Nov.23 = c(0.56, 0.46, 0.66), Dec.23 = c(0.76, 0.74, 0.96)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)); colMeans(X[-1])` returning `Oct.23 Nov.23 Dec.23 
  0.54   0.56   0.82`

Comment: You have created the variable `z_name`, not the column `df$z_name` (in data.frame `df`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do `df[,26] %>% mean()`, or since it's always the LAST column you can do `df[,ncol(df)] %>% mean()`. That last one works as follows: `ncol(df)` gives you the number of columns in your data frame (26) in your case, and then pass that number into the columns of the `df`, remember that on a data frame you specify the row location in the first place `df[row, ]` and column location in the second place `df[ ,column]`.